# Why does this class behave differently when I don't supply a generic type?

Tags: java, generics

I don't understand why this confuses the compiler.  I'm using the generic type `T` to hold an object that's not related to the `put` and `get` methods.  I always thought `GenericClass` and `GenericClass<Object>` were functionally identical, but I must be mistaken.  When compiling the `DoesntWork` class I get `incompatible types - required: String - found: Object`.  The `Works` class does what I expect.  What's going on here?

```java
public class GenericClass<T> {
    public <V> void put(Class<V> key, V value) {
        // put into map
    }

    public <V> V get(Class<V> key) {
        // get from map
        return null;
    }

    public static class DoesntWork {
        public DoesntWork() {
            GenericClass genericClass = new GenericClass();
            String s = genericClass.get(String.class);
        }
    }

    public static class Works {
        public Works() {
            GenericClass<Object> genericClass = new GenericClass<Object>();
            String s = genericClass.get(String.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `genericClass` is closer to `genericClass<?>` than to `genericClass<Object>`

Comment: That being said, I can't see why `DoesntWork` shouldn't work.

Comment: Try forcing the type: `genericClass.<String>get(String.class)` (not sure it's the correct syntax)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing about how raw types work -- generic types that you've left out the arguments for -- is that *all* generics for them and their methods are erased as well.  So for a raw `GenericClass`, the `get` and `put` methods *also* lose their generics.

Comment: The use of raw types is, essentially, an indication that you're using legacy, pre-generics code, for the purposes of compatibility; most of the weirdnesses around raw types are hacks for compatibility purposes.  [JLS 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) has more details.

Comment: But for an example of why this specific behavior is necessary, consider the following example: legacy code built with Java 1.4 has to get the same behavior from `List` from Java 1.4 -- pre-generics -- and from `List` from Java 5, which was rewritten to introduce generics.  It's awkward, but necessary for backwards compatibility -- but it should never be an issue for new code, since new code should basically never use raw types.

Comment: "new code should basically never use raw types" - I can agree with that.

Comment: So if I don't know the type when working on an object, I should use `?`?  Ex: Vehicle<T> with a washing decorator should use `wash(Vehicle<?> vehicle)` instead of `wash(Vehicle vehicle)`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you work with a generic class without the extra type information you work with what is sometimes called the `degenerate` form of the class. The `degenerate` form has ALL generic type information removed.

Essentially - your class becomes something like:

```
public class GenericClass {
    public void put(Class key, Object value) {
        // put into map
    }

    public Object get(Class key) {
        // get from map
        return null;
    }

    ...
}
```

The compiler response you are seeing is therefore expected behaviour.

It's mentioned in a [Java Puzzlers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbp-3BJWsU8).