# Java Generic Type Inference Strange Behavior?

Tags: java, generics, types, type-inference, type-erasure

Can someone explain this behaviour to me:

**Note: That T is never used in SomeThingGeneric**

```
   public static class SomeThingGeneric<T> {
        public List<String> getSomeList() {
            return null;
        }
    }

final SomeThingGeneric<Object> someThingGenericObject = new SomeThingGeneric<Object>();
final SomeThingGeneric<?> someThingGenericWildcard    = new SomeThingGeneric<Object>();
final SomeThingGeneric someThingGenericRaw            = new SomeThingGeneric<Object>();

for (final String s : someThingGenericObject.getSomeList()) { }   // 1 - compiles
for (final String s : someThingGenericWildcard.getSomeList()) { } // 2 - compiles
for (final String s : someThingGenericRaw.getSomeList()) { }      // 3 - does not compile!
```

(1) and (2) compiles but (3) fails with following message:

```
incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
```

If anyone wants the full code, [here it is](https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/50e34ea94b5d2ab76e818536492d597629a02113/temp/SandBox/Something.java). I have verified this in both Java 5 and 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this class behave differently when I don't supply a generic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735235/why-does-this-class-behave-differently-when-i-dont-supply-a-generic-type)

Comment: Nevertheless, the question and the answer both apply here.  (In particular, the answer is "it was done this way for backwards compatibility, and it shouldn't be an issue because you should never use raw types in new code.")

Comment: @wrick `Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.` - what else, besides the citations from the JLS, would you like to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is an interesting question despite the downvotes. I believe the answer to the question lies in this portion of the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), **instance method** (§8.4, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from
>   its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds
>   to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to
>   C.

Effectively, your method `public List<String> getSomeList` gets an effective signature of `public List getSomeList`, in the scenario where you accessing it via a raw type. And as such, the list iterator for the resulting list then 'returns' objects instead of strings.

Comment: There is no particularly good reason that I can think of or have found in any text. If the fields/methods were typed to the generic parameter of the class that would make (obvious) sense. Could be to enable some kind of compatibility with legacy code. Nevertheless, the behavior is documented in the JLS, fwiw.

Answer (score 3):

The code can be broken down to the following SSCCE:

```
public static class SomeThingGeneric<T> {
    public List<String> getSomeList() {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final SomeThingGeneric someThingGenericRaw = new SomeThingGeneric<Object>();
    for (final String s : someThingGenericRaw.getSomeList()) { }        //  SAD compiler.  WTF?
}
```

This results in the compiler error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String`.

The question is: why does this error occur? `T` is not used anywhere in `SomeThingGeneric`, and especially not in the signature of the `getSomeList()` method. So, when we call `getSomeList()`, we should get a `List<String>`. However, we obviously get a raw `List` type.

---

The reason is type erasure. From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6):

> Type erasure also maps the signature (§8.4.2) of a constructor or **method** to a signature that has **no parameterized types or type variables.**

And, [the definition of a `raw type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) says:

> To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, it is possible to use as a type **the erasure (§4.6) of a parameterized type** (§4.5) or the erasure of an array type (§10.1) whose element type is a parameterized type. **Such a type is called a raw type**.

So, when using a *raw type*, it is the *generic type* with type erasure applied. When applying type erasure, all method signatures are mapped to types with no type parameters or type variables. Hence, the method `List<String> getSomeList()` from the example becomes `List getSomeList()` which results in the shown compiler error.

Comment: But note that I do not use T anywhere in SomeThingGeneric

Comment: Ah, good point - did not recognize this at first ... lets see ... (by the way, that is the reason why it is useful to describe the issue a littlebit in the question ;) )

Comment: I did not downvote ;) Did you check with an earlier compiler version (1.6 / 1.5)?

Comment: Fails in both 1.6 and 1.5. Did not check 1.7+

Comment: Also fails with 1.7 (Eclipse). I suppose that this is somehow related to type erasure, but did not find a reference yet ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27825/discussion-between-andreas-and-wrick)

Comment: Glad to see you incorporated my JLS quote into your answer. But you might want to remove the first quote as its not directly related to the actual problem (and comes from section 4.6, not 4.8).

Comment: I agree that the link was wrong (thanks - fixed that), but does the part you quoted not describe the erasure **corresponding to the generic  parameter itself** (which would be `T` in the example above)? IMHO, the fact that also non-related generic type parameters (like <String> from the sample above) are also erased, is described more precisely in §4.6

Answer (score 3):

Answer: When you instantiate a generic type as a raw type, ALL of it's type instantiations are removed, leaving raw types everywhere (even if they don't relate to Type parameters, such as T in your Q).  i.e. raw types are 100% "generics-free".

Reason: backwards compatability with pre-generic code.

Answer (score 0):

For my opinion is a bug. Because it must work. The signature of the method do not use the generic T type. So it must compile.

Mark the entire class as erasure, do not compiling the very well defined generic methods, is not good.

Please report it.

Comment: Its not a bug. It is well documented in the JLS.

Comment: The signature of the method is very well defined, so still I do not see the logic behind it to be rejected.

Comment: The logic is: do not use raw types. They are provided for compatibility reasons only. See the link from @Louis in his comment.

Comment: Right, but do not compile any NOT erasure methods of a erasure class, it must not be acceptable, because the line of code consume a very well generic defined method and is still compatible, because the raw behavior is always there.

Comment: When you design a language, you should keep this in mind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment